# I would like to change the font-size of my headerName in ag-grid

Tags: ag-grid, font-size

this seems like such a simple thing to do, but I can't seem to do it. I've tried using CSS in my scss file, like this:

```
.ag-header-cell-text {
  font-size: 8px;
  color: red;
  background-color: red;
}

or like this:

.ag-header-cell
  font-size: 8px;
  color: red;
  background-color: red;
}
```

but nothing changes, not the color either. setting the headerheight works but doesn't help me. I just want the font smaller.

```
I've also tried adding a cellStyle property to the columnDefs, but nothing seems to works, nor can I find a solution. Please help.
```

Comment: Just tried to use your styles and it works well. Perhaps you have some other styles that get over your definition - try to use 'important!' with your style like 'font-size: 8px important!;' to verify - if it does not help, please create a plunker with the code. Please verify also if the css file is well generated and loaded by page.

Comment: try making changes to this class .ag-header-cell-label .ag-header-cell-text

Answer (score 0):

Adding !important may work.Or maybe your class names don't correct. Check it by f12 (inspect) and correct.

```
  .ag-header-cell-text {
      font-size: 8px !important;
      color: red !important;
      background-color: red !important;
    }
    .ag-header-cell
      font-size: 8px !important;
      color: red !important;
      background-color: red !important;
    }
```